# SFML unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker-errors, sfml

Please see the following screenshots:
[image: Additional Include directories]

[image: Preprocessor]

[image: Linker Additional Library Directory]

[image: Linker Input Additional Dependancies]

I have followed all of this from their official documentation for visual studio (2022 preview) ... and yet i still get these errors:
[image: Linker errors]

[image: Errors]

Please note I am using their boiler-plate hello world code to test all of this. I know im doing something simply wrong but I cannot for the life of me figure it out.

```
Error   LNK1120 19 unresolved externals SFMLTest    C:\Users\Jorda\source\repos\SFMLTest\Release\SFMLTest.exe   1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp___CrtDbgReport SFMLTest    C:\Users\Jorda\source\repos\SFMLTest\SFMLTest\Main.obj  1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp___invalid_parameter    SFMLTest    C:\Users\Jorda\source\repos\SFMLTest\SFMLTest\Main.obj  1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp___calloc_dbg   SFMLTest    C:\Users\Jorda\source\repos\SFMLTest\SFMLTest\Main.obj  1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: static class sf::RenderStates const sf::RenderStates::Default" (?Default@RenderStates@sf@@2V12@B)   SFMLTest    C:\Users\Jorda\source\repos\SFMLTest\SFMLTest\Main.obj  1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall sf::CircleShape::CircleShape(float,unsigned int)" (??0CircleShape@sf@@QAE@MI@Z)  SFMLTest    C:\Users\Jorda\source\repos\SFMLTest\SFMLTest\Main.obj  1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __thiscall sf::RenderWindow::~RenderWindow(void)" (??1RenderWindow@sf@@UAE@XZ)  SFMLTest    C:\Users\Jorda\source\repos\SFMLTest\SFMLTest\Main.obj  1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall sf::RenderWindow::RenderWindow(class sf::VideoMode,class sf::String const &,unsigned int,struct sf::ContextSettings const &)" (??0RenderWindow@sf@@QAE@VVideoMode@1@ABVString@1@IABUContextSettings@1@@Z)    SFMLTest    C:\Users\Jorda\source\repos\SFMLTest\SFMLTest\Main.obj  1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall sf::Color::Color(unsigned char,unsigned char,unsigned char,unsigned char)" (??0Color@sf@@QAE@EEEE@Z) SFMLTest    C:\Users\Jorda\source\repos\SFMLTest\SFMLTest\Main.obj  1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall sf::Window::display(void)" (?display@Window@sf@@QAEXXZ) SFMLTest    C:\Users\Jorda\source\repos\SFMLTest\SFMLTest\Main.obj  1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: bool __thiscall sf::Window::pollEvent(class sf::Event &)" (?pollEvent@Window@sf@@QAE_NAAVEvent@2@@Z)    SFMLTest    C:\Users\Jorda\source\repos\SFMLTest\SFMLTest\Main.obj  1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: bool __thiscall sf::Window::isOpen(void)const " (?isOpen@Window@sf@@QBE_NXZ)    SFMLTest    C:\Users\Jorda\source\repos\SFMLTest\SFMLTest\Main.obj  1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall sf::Window::close(void)" (?close@Window@sf@@QAEXXZ) SFMLTest    C:\Users\Jorda\source\repos\SFMLTest\SFMLTest\Main.obj  1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: static class sf::Color const sf::Color::Green" (?Green@Color@sf@@2V12@B)    SFMLTest    C:\Users\Jorda\source\repos\SFMLTest\SFMLTest\Main.obj  1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall sf::RenderTarget::draw(class sf::Drawable const &,class sf::RenderStates const &)" (?draw@RenderTarget@sf@@QAEXABVDrawable@2@ABVRenderStates@2@@Z)  SFMLTest    C:\Users\Jorda\source\repos\SFMLTest\SFMLTest\Main.obj  1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall sf::RenderTarget::clear(class sf::Color const &)" (?clear@RenderTarget@sf@@QAEXABVColor@2@@Z)   SFMLTest    C:\Users\Jorda\source\repos\SFMLTest\SFMLTest\Main.obj  1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall sf::Shape::setFillColor(class sf::Color const &)" (?setFillColor@Shape@sf@@QAEXABVColor@2@@Z)   SFMLTest    C:\Users\Jorda\source\repos\SFMLTest\SFMLTest\Main.obj  1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __thiscall sf::Shape::~Shape(void)" (??1Shape@sf@@UAE@XZ)   SFMLTest    C:\Users\Jorda\source\repos\SFMLTest\SFMLTest\Main.obj  1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall sf::String::String(char const *,class std::locale const &)" (??0String@sf@@QAE@PBDABVlocale@std@@@Z) SFMLTest    C:\Users\Jorda\source\repos\SFMLTest\SFMLTest\Main.obj  1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall sf::VideoMode::VideoMode(unsigned int,unsigned int,unsigned int)" (??0VideoMode@sf@@QAE@III@Z)   SFMLTest    C:\Users\Jorda\source\repos\SFMLTest\SFMLTest\Main.obj  1
```

Comment: In ome image you have the (partial) build output as text. Please copy-paste that text, in full and complete, and as text, into your question.

Comment: Hi @Someprogrammerdude, I have now done this

Comment: Please don't add "C++" into the title - we have tags for that purpose. Please don't add "SOLVED" into the title - that's what accepted answers are for.

Answer (score 2):

I have just solved this problem.
I deleted "SFML_STATIC" in Preprocessor

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so essentially I re-did everything by watching this guy:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lFzpkvrscs4

The differences from what i originally did and from watching that tutorial:

1. The order in which I added the linker inputs
2. I wasn't using 64-bit (facepalm)

Answer (score 1):

The problem I was running into with Visual Studio 2022 and SFML was that as the time of this posting the pre-built libraries of SFML available to download from [www.sfml-dev.org](http://www.sfml-dev.org) were 32-bit libraries. The default targeted platform for VS 2022 appears to be 64-bit. So I changed the target system from "x64" to "Win32" and then I was able to get it to work.

Keep in mind that I did have to update the project settings for the additional include and library directories again after changing the target platform.

---

Nevermind, I see in your screenshots that you are already targeting Win32. Maybe it will help someone else though to keep this in mind.